# Laravel `assertSee` failing because timestamps are backwards?

Tags: laravel

I've made a feature test that checks if the correct amount of news articles is returned to the user.

The intended output is that it returns 10 articles in Descending order.

`Feature Test:`

```
    public function a_user_can_view_news_articles()
    {
        $articles = factory(NewsArticle::class, 50)->create();
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $this->actingAs($user)
            ->get('/api/news-articles')
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJsonCount(10)
            ->assertSee($articles->sortByDesc('created_at')->take(10));
    }
```

`Route:`

```
Route::get('/news-articles', function ()
{
    $articles = NewsArticle::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get()->take(10);
    return response()->json($articles);
});
```

But the test fails as not containing the same content, and as you can see below, the only difference is that the timestamp positions in the array are inverted. I've got no idea why this happens and I've got no clue how to fix it.

[image: alt]

Hopefully someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamps are backwards in the test because `Eloquent`'s [FactoryBuilder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php#L178)'s `create` function stores the attributes defined in the Model Factory **BEFORE** filling the rest of the attributes (i.e `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) and it returns them in that order
So assuming a `NewsArticleFactory` like this

```php
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\NewsArticle;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(NewsArticle::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'image' => $faker->imageUrl(),
        'content' => $faker->text,
    ];
});
```

[Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php#L178](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php#L178)

```php
public function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    $results = $this->make($attributes); // Only 'image` and 'content'
    if ($results instanceof Model) {
            $this->store(collect([$results]));

            $this->callAfterCreating(collect([$results]));
    } else {
            $this->store($results);
            // Other columns in the database table are inserted AFTER
            dump($results); // 'image', 'content', 'updated_at', 'created_at', 'id'

            $this->callAfterCreating($results);
    }
    return $results;
}
```

And a call to `factory(NewsArticle::class)->create();`....
This is what we get:

```
=> App\NewsArticle {#3143
     image: "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?66495",
     content: "Est minima eveniet est nulla adipisci ut eos. Cupiditate beatae porro corporis ut aut reprehenderit esse. Vel debitis cumque dicta cum maxime. Quis iusto et ducimus voluptatem laboriosam rem.",
     updated_at: "2019-09-02 13:53:26",
     created_at: "2019-09-02 13:53:26",
     id: 351,
   }
```

But `Eloquent` returns the columns properly ordered as defined in your migration which causes the mismatch.
So a solution is to manually add the auto-incrementing `id`, the `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps in the `Model Factory` like so:

```php
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\NewsArticle;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
$autoIncrement = autoIncrement();

$factory->define(NewsArticle::class, function (Faker $faker) use ($autoIncrement) {
    $autoIncrement->next();
    return [
        'id' => $autoIncrement->current(),
        'image' => $faker->imageUrl(),
        'content' => $faker->text,
        'created_at' => now(),
        'updated_at' => now(),
    ];
});

function autoIncrement()
{
    $last_id = optional(NewsArticle::latest()->first())->id ?? 0;
    for ($i = $last_id; $i < 50; $i++) {
        yield $i;
    }
}
```

Now a factory call returns the correct order

```
>>> factory(App\NewsArticle::class)->create();
=> App\NewsArticle {#3143
     id: 1,
     image: "https://lorempixel.com/640/480/?70536",
     content: "Nesciunt quibusdam architecto suscipit sint. Aut quaerat qui dolores ut dolores alias inventore eveniet. Voluptatem sed voluptatibus quo.",
     created_at: "2019-09-02 14:00:13",
     updated_at: "2019-09-02 14:00:13",
   }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This still doesn't fix it. Now it complains about the timestamps being the wrong format. This seems really over the top to fix a basic problem and really doesn't explain why the timestamps are backwards in the first place? :/

Comment: Updated the answer with as much details I could gather @Borassign